# invariant subspaces intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

If there are two subspaces of Euclidean space of dimension $n$, denoted as $R_1$ and $R_2$. Suppose that $M$ is $n$ by $n$ matrix, and suppose that $R_1$, $R_2$ and their orthogonal complement are invariant with left multiplication of $M$.

The problem is to prove that the orthogonal complement of intersection of $R_1$ and $R_2$ are invariant with $M$ as well.

Comment: are you saying that if $M(R_i)\subset R_i$ and $M(R_i^\perp) \subset R_i^\perp $ then $M({(R_1\cap R_2)}^\perp)\subset {(R_1\cap R_2)}^\perp$